# URDF with tool-changer

Tags: urdf, robot-state-publisher, ros-industrial, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Consider the application of a robot w/ tool changer that needs to update its URDF.

I'd like to dynamically change the origin of a joint that connects an END_EFFECTOR link to a TOOL link.

The approaches I can think of are:

**Model the joint as a FIXED joint**

My first approach was to model the joint as a fixed joint, and publish its transform to /tf myself. However robot_state_publisher continued to publish the transform described in the URDF, conflicting with the values I was publishing. I could patch robot_state_publisher, but I'd like to avoid modifying a standard library if possible.

Then I tried taking the approach of parsing the robot_description rosparam, modifying its XML, and writing it back to the rosparam whenever the tool changed. I believe this is how the calibration stack handles adjusting fixed joints. But I don't think a change to the robot_description rosparam is propagated to robot_state_publisher at run-time unless I modify it to use dynamic_reconfigure, for example.

**Model the joint as a FLOATING joint**

I thought this could work and I could publish the transform to /tf directly without conflicting with robot_state_publisher. But in my Electric install the kdl_parser does not support 'FLOATING' type joints. It throws the warning "Converting unknown joint type into a fixed joint". After reading [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4000) I'm very confused as to whether floating joints are supported at all.

**Model the joint as the sum of six REVOLUTE joints**

This is the approach suggested by Wim [here](https://code.ros.org/gf/project/ros/mailman/?_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=23468&action=ListThreads&mailman_id=20). Then robot_state_publisher could be responsible for publishing to /tf, but it seems ugly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49818/urdf-with-tool-changer/) by [isherman](https://answers.ros.org/users/2938/isherman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it have to be a single URDF?  What about a URDF for the arm and a seperate one for the tool. A node could be written to publish the transform between the tool and the robot, when it is connected, and otherwise to some other frame.

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1